# set multiple MMCloseDrawerGestureMode gestures

Tags: mmdrawercontroller

I am using MMDrawerController and I wish to set multiple closing gestures, anyone know if this is possible?  If so how do I accomplish this?

Currently I am doing this:

```
 [destinationViewController setCloseDrawerGestureModeMask:MMCloseDrawerGestureModePanningCenterView];
```

Comment: On their GitHub page it says: "You are free to set whatever combination you want for opening and closing." But I haven't figured out how, yet.
https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController

Comment: exact same issue I am having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if you still need help with this, but to set multiple closing gestures:

```
 [destinationViewController setCloseDrawerGestureModeMask:MMCloseDrawerGestureModePanningCenterView | MMCloseDrawerGestureModeTapCenterView];
```

Add however many you wish